# Why do I want to shift left in this scenario?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

I am currently working on Part B of the following question in order to implement the new command (LWI). The textbook recommends that in order to implement it I must extend the ALU to shift left. Why do I want to shift left in this case?  If so how would I go about extending the ALU to accept SLL?

Question Part B

[image: Question Part B]

Datapath In Question

[image: Datapath In Question]

Thanks!

Comment: You should quote the relevant text in your question, not just link to pictures of it!

Comment: Its from Computer Organization and Design : https://www.amazon.com/Computer-Organization-Design-MIPS-Fifth/dp/0124077269

Comment: @LousSinclair That's not how you do it on this site. Every question should be self-contained.

Comment: They want to shift left by 2 then? If so, they wrote down the specification of `LWI` confusingly - from the way they wrote it, I would assume it uses the sum as the address, possibly generating an alignment exception (or silently doing the wrong thing because there is no alignment check in the diagram).